# Specify personal view in MS CRM 2011 lookup window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to launch look-up window from MS CRM 2011 ribbon. It's not linked to the field and results will be used in custom JScript afterwards.

But tricky thing is that I'm trying to create personal view before that in JScript and make this look-up window use it.

The windows opens successfully, the correct view is selected in the drop down box, however the view is not applied to the entries. If I select another view (no matter system or custom) and then select my personal view once again — it shows entries correctly.

Does anybody faced such situation before? Maybe I'm missing something?

Here is piece of my JScript code:

```
var view = {
    Name:               "Temporary Team View",
    UserQueryId:        Guid.Create(),
    QueryType:          0,
    ReturnedTypeCode:   "team",
    FetchXml:           xml 
};

// JavaScript code sending REST request to create UserQuery entry is here.
// The code below executes as part of success callback.

var result = window.showModalDialog("/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?Browse=1&DisableViewPicker=1&objecttypes=9&LookupStyle=multi&DefaultViewId=" + view.UserQueryId, null, "dialogWidth: 600px; dialogHeight: 600px");
```

Comment: You are using a temporary lookup to add the view before call the dialog? because I don't see where you applied the fetchxml

Comment: @GuidoPreite, I'm sending REST request to create UserQuery entry. And this personal view appears in the view selectors for teams system-wide (but for me only of course). I will add the code, it uses jQuery wrapper for sending requests.

Comment: is not necessary, I created a personal view and I replicated your issue

Comment: Did some test, unfortunately looks like is not possible with personal view, because if is selected a system view (also a custom one) it works correctly, very strange.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, really strange, since selecting another view (even personal one) and getting back to original — shows correct list. I would report this to Microsoft, probably.